# iMacros EVAL not giving proper output

Tags: javascript, macros, eval, substring, imacros

Ok, so I'm trying to scrape some information from a website to try and interpret a value like 11/22 [50%].  I can guarantee the value will be at least the minimum required by the size of the substring.  So far the code works to find the data, extract it and set it to !VAR1. However for some reason I can't get it to put !VAR2 in to the input field on the page.  It switches correctly, it finds the input field and inputs "Extraction Results: " and that's it.

So my input is 11/22 [50%], I only want the 11. So I'm splitting the string from position 1,2 giving me 11.

According to the iMacros wiki my syntax is correct, the macro runs, and I'm just not getting the expected output, I assume because of my EVAL line.  Does anyone know why? Also an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
'Go to website
URL GOTO=http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

'Set tag to refer to next
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:Nerve:

'Get the relative position of something that cannot be tagged and extract the cell's info
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

'Set VAR1 to Extracted info (For debugging)
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}

'Issue must be here, this is trying to run javascript substring on the information harvested.
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s=s.substring(1,2); s;")

"Extract to null value to be referenced later
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Test VAR2 by going to another page and posting the info in a textbox.
URL GOTO=http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:search[id] CONTENT=Extraction<SP>results:{{!VAR2}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I changed, I copied the code I posted here in to a new iMacro and ran it and it worked. Changed the substring to get what I wanted. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: Still, this won't work for all input. Try my updated answer with the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s=s.split(\"/\")[0];s;")
```

The String.split() function splits the string into an array, each part being separated when it finds whatever you give as an argument, which will either be a RegExp or String.

The first object in the array ([0]) will be the text before the first "/" was found.

Then I `return s`, so eval(); will return the correct output.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't compile, it gives an error pointing to that line of code. I don't know if split is supported in iMacros.

Comment: SyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line: 7 (Error code: -910)

Comment: SyntaxError: return not in function, line: 7 (Error code: -1001)

I removed the return statement and it worked with the \". So you had to escape them from the command to make split work?

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to do that for any string.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Helped me understand why a bunch of my EVAL's weren't working as expected.